# How to load mysqli extension inside docker-compose.yml file with NGINX, PHP-FPM

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, docker, docker-compose

When loading docker-compose up, wordpress loads on the url but the mysqli_connect function is undefined because of the absence of the extension.

I have tried to add the following under the fpm image

command: "docker-php-ext-install mysqli"

I have tried to add a Dockerfile into the directory of the docker-compose.yml file containing

````
version: "3"

services:
  #database
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: wordpress
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
    networks:
      - wpsite
  # webserver
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    links:
      - fpm
    volumes:
      - /Users/connergesbocker/Github/cbgesbocker/dotfiles/root/etc/nginx/conf.d/village.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/village.conf
      - /Users/connergesbocker/WordPress:/WordPress
    networks:
      - wpsite
  # phpmyadmin
  phpmyadmin:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8888:8888"
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: wordpress
    networks:
      - wpsite
  fpm:
    image: php:5.6.20-fpm
    ports:
      - "90:9000"
    # command: "docker-php-ext-install mysqli"
    links:
      - db
    volumes:
      - /Users/connergesbocker/WordPress:/WordPress
    working_dir: "/"
    networks:
      - wpsite
networks:
  wpsite:
volumes:
  db_data:```
````

Answer (score 6):

You could customize your dockerfile & add install in it:

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM php:5.6.20-fpm
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli
```

**Part of docker-compose.yaml:**

```
fpm:
  build: .
  image: myphp:1
  ports:
    - "90:9000"
  # command: "docker-php-ext-install mysqli"
  links:
    - db
  volumes:
    - /Users/connergesbocker/WordPress:/WordPress
  working_dir: "/"
  networks:
    - wpsite
```

Comment: I had to change this slightly to get it to work for me. My `docker-compose.yml` file is `version: '3'` and I did:

```
services:
  php:
      build:
        context: ./php
```

With the `Dockerfile` sat at `./php/Dockerfile` relative to my `docker-compose.yml`

Answer (score 3):

your override will install the extension but the container will stop after installation because `php-fpm` will not start by overriding `CMD`. Replace the command with below one.

```
command:
  - /bin/sh
  - -c
  - |
      docker-php-ext-install mysqli 
      echo "extension installed.....starting php-fpm........................................"
      php-fpm
```

[image]

Comment: The disadvantage of this (vs a separate `Dockerfile` per the other answer) is that it seems to run the install command every time I `docker-compose up`